# Integrate Apache Felix in Websphere v8.5

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, websphere-8, osgi-bundle

We have a requirement to integrate Apache Felix as a the osgi container in Websphere v85 and deploy web applications (.war). Appreciate your help in suggesting documentation/reference to this.

Thanks

Comment: This requirement is a little strange. WebSphere is already built on an OSGi Framework, though it is Equinox rather than Felix. I don't think it would be practical to switch the underlying framework to Felix, but why would you need to do this? If you require OSGi features then they are already provided.

Answer (score 1):

There is some documentation on how to embed Apache Felix in a WAR here:

http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html#using-the-servlet-bridge

That piece of documentation also refers to an example:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/trunk/http/samples/bridge/

I do agree with Neil that is is a bit strange to have such a requirement, so perhaps you can explain that?